# Call to undefined method App\Models\Comment::comments()

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, comments, blogs

I wanted to add comment to every post I make but I keep on getting errors.

Comment Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $comments = new Comment;
    $comments->body =$request->get('comment_body');
    $comments->user()->associate($request->user());
    $blogs = Comment::find(1);
    $blogs->comments()->save($comments);

    return back();
}
```

Comment Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded =[];

    public function blog()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Blog::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Blog Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id' , 'blog_category_id' , 'title' , 'description'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(user::class);
    }

    public function blogcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(BlogCategory::class)->withDefault(function($user , $post){
            $user->name = "Author";
        });
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why are you trying to find a Comment instead of a Blog post `$blogs = Comment::find(1)` ? The Blog model has the `comments` relationship, not the Comment model

Comment: but i have try it. keep on repeating the error

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong model; the Blog model has the `comments` relationship not the Comment model:

```
$blog = Blog::find(...);
$blog->comments()->save(...);
```

**Update:**

You seem to want to be using a Polymorphic relationship it would seem based on the structure of your `comments` table since you have the fields `commentable_id` and `commentable_type`. If you check the documentation for the Polymorphic One to Many relationship this is the same as the example in the documentation:

Blog model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

Comment model:

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Polymorphic Relationships - One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-model-structure)

Having said that, your Comment model doesn't look like you wanted to use a polymorphic relationship since you specifically had a `blog` relationship method. If you do not have more than 1 entity that needs to be related to Comment I would not be using a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: i got this error after changing the model

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'blog_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `comments` (`body`, `user_id`, `blog_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hey, ?, 1, 2021-08-20 21:01:45, 2021-08-20 21:01:45))

Comment: then your schema isn't setup for convention or you need to adjust the relationship method to accomodate for the column you are using to hold the blog's id ... you are saying `Comment` belongs to `Blog` so the `comments` table needs some field for that Blog id

Comment: this  is my comment table

Comment: $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('commentable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
         });
    }

Comment: you have the wrong relationship method if you are trying to use a polymorphic relationship

Comment: pls could you just tell me what to do

Comment: @Peter updated for your polymorphic relationship

Comment: Call to a member function comments() on null

Comment: `find` can return `null`, you have to check for these things ... this has gotten to the point of being outside the scope of the original question though